# Make an optional option required when another one is defined in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to define `certificate` and `privateKey` required when `secure` flag is set to true. Is this possible to achieve?

```json
{
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        'secure': {
            title: 'Serve files over HTTPS',
            description: 'Flag telling whether to serve contents over HTTPS and WSS',

            type: 'boolean',
            default: false
        },

        'certificate': {
            title: 'Certificate file',
            description: 'Location of the certificate file',

            type: 'string'
        },

        'privateKey': {
            title: 'Private key file',
            description: 'Location of the private key file',

            type: 'string'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'dependencies' keyword.

```
{
  dependencies: {
    secure: ['certificate', 'privateKey']
  }
}
```

You can even specify the schema the data should match when secure is present:

```
{
  dependencies: {
    secure: {
      properties: {
        certificate: {
          type: 'string'
        }
        privateKey: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: ['certificate', 'privateKey']
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to have the schema content-dependent?  I mean "what the schema allows depends on what's in the target (json) content"?

You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it isn't pretty.  You need to use the `anyOf` keyword to define how you want it to validate when `secure` is `true` and how you want it to validate when `secure` is `false`.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "secure": {
      "title": "Serve files over HTTPS",
      "description": "Flag telling whether to serve contents over HTTPS and WSS",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "secure": {
          "enum": [true]
        },
        "certificate": {
          "title": "Certificate file",
          "description": "Location of the certificate file",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "privateKey": {
          "title": "Private key file",
          "description": "Location of the private key file",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": ["certificate", "privateKey"]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "secure": {
          "enum": [false]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```